# Copy Stored procedure from one database to another database dynamically

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I used this sql but it's not working

```
SELECT @objname= OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID(N''+@fromDatabase+'..'+@spName))    
print @objname    
SET @objname = REPLACE(@objname,'''','''''')    
SET @objname = 'USE ['+@toDatabase+']; GO  EXEC(''' + @objname + ''')'  
EXEC(@objname)
```

Here `OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID('myprocedure'))` this function same working as

```
SELECT    [definition] FROM    sys.sql_modules WHERE    object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyProcedure')
```

But I need something like as

```
SELECT    [definition] FROM    **@from_db**.sys.sql_modules WHERE    object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyProcedure')
```

Comment: This is probably super clear to you because you are knee deep in this but we can't see you screen and have no idea what you are trying to do here. Give us some details about what you are trying to do and we can help.

Comment: Here , consider a scenario i am connected with "ABC" database  and want Stored procedure copy from "XYZ" database to "AAA" database.. but here need connect to "XYZ" database to copy SP's to "AAA" database.

Comment: You can retrieve data from other databases simply by putting the database name where you have it. You would have to use dynamic sql like you did in the part you already posted.

Comment: Does this have to be done on the fly / dynamically? Why not script the SPs you want,and transfer them over to the other db?

Comment: Is it possible like this..  SELECT    [definition] FROM    [@from_db].sys.sql_modules WHERE    object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyProcedure')   or any other way same like this.